# How To List Sibling Pages And Include The Featured Image?

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I recently came across this [cool tutorial](http://wordimpress.com/list-only-sibling-pages-using-wp_list_pages/) on listing sibling pages.  Below is the suggested code:

```
<?php
    //GET CHILD PAGES IF THERE ARE ANY
    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
 
    //GET PARENT PAGE IF THERE IS ONE
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
 
    //DO WE HAVE SIBLINGS?
    $siblings =  get_pages('child_of='.$parent);
 
    if( count($children) != 0) {
       $args = array(
         'depth' => 1,
         'title_li' => '',
         'child_of' => $post->ID
       );
 
    } elseif($parent != 0) {
        $args = array(
             'depth' => 1,
             'title_li' => '',
             'exclude' => $post->ID,
             'child_of' => $parent
           );
    }
    //Show pages if this page has more than one sibling 
    // and if it has children 
    if(count($siblings) > 1 && !is_null($args))   
    {?>
    <div class="widget subpages">
    <h3 class="widgettitle">Also in this Section</h3>
         <ul class="pages-list">
         <?php wp_list_pages($args);  ?>
         </ul>
     </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I was wondering how can I can modify the above code snippet to include the **featured image, post title, and permalink**.  I would like to imitate "related posts".

Looking forward to your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_list_pages` only displays page title and link in list. Try following code to fetch page content and thumbnail.

```
<ul class="pages-list">
           <?php $our_pages = get_pages($args); ?>
           <?php if (!empty($our_pages)): ?>
            <?php foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item): ?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>"><?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?></a>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_item->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>
              </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
           <?php endif ?>
           </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input!  sending you a private message on nilambar.net :-)

Comment: If you want the original image that was uploaded, you can change this: 
`get_the_post_thumbnail($page_item->ID,'original'); `